# Debugging SFINAE in gcc or clang

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, clang

I would like to know how my template/s are expanded at compile time given a specific invocation, in particular I'm interested in getting to know more about all the possible use and behaviours of the technique called SFINAE.

Do you know about a flag or more flags in `gcc` and/or `clang` that can help me with that ?

Comment: add some trace messages to your source.

Comment: @BryanChen maybe I wasn't that clear about what I want; I want to debug what happens to my templates at compile time and which template gets called with a given call/overload.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath that will work, but it sounds so so verbose

Comment: you can try -fdump-rtl-all

Answer (score 0):

"All the possible behaviors of SFINAE" is too vague and too broad. But - if you want to get an idea of how a compiler instantiates the templates in your code, this might work for you:

> **Templight* is a Clang-based tool to profile the time and memory consumption of template instantiations and to perform interactive debugging sessions to gain introspection into the template instantiation process.

[Templight](https://github.com/mikael-s-persson/templight) seems to instrument the front-end part of the compilation process, so that later, you can use a visualizer named [templater](https://github.com/schulmar/Templar).

Caveat: I haven't tried doing that myself.